# Error of sorting program (HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED)

Tags: c++, sorting

This program is about the bubbleSort, insertionSort and qsort time.

I run my program and got the Debug Error,

```
HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED:after Normal block(#152)at 0x006613C0 CRT Detected
```

that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

Then, I delete the last 3 lines code (delete[] a;delete[] b;delete[] c) in the `void part_1(int n)` to make it work. And my professor told me "Your program should have other errors, those errors cause the
failures in the delete statements."and I should not delete the last 3 lines code. I can't find it. Please Help.

```
// Part-1 : --------------------------- sorting algorithms

void bubbleSort(double *x, int n)
{
// Implement the sorting function using the bubble sort algorithm.
double temp;
for (int j = 0;j < n;j++) {
    for (int i = 0;i < n;i++) {
        if (x[i] > x[i + 1]) {
            temp = x[i];
            x[i + 1] = x[i];
            x[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
  }
}


void insertionSort(double *x, int n)
   {
// Implement the sorting function using the insertion sort algorithm.

for (int i = 1;i < n;i++) {
    double temp = x[i];
    int j = 0;
    for (j = i - 1;j >= 0 && x[j]>temp;j--) {
        x[j + 1] = x[j];
    }
    x[j + 1] = temp;
  }

}


int compare_1(const void *a, const void *b) {
double *X = (double *)a;
double *Y = (double *)b;
if (*X > *Y) {
    return 1;
}
else if (*X < *Y)
    return -1;
return 0;

}

void part_1(int n)
{
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));  // set the seed of the random number generator

double *a = new double[n];  // create 3 arrays with identical contents
double *b = new double[n];
double *c = new double[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    a[i] = b[i] = c[i] = rand() / 10000.0;

clock_t begin, end;
double elapsedTime;

cout << "Bubble sort: sorting an array of size " << n << endl;
begin = clock();
bubbleSort(a, n);
end = clock();

elapsedTime = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
cout << "Elapsed time = " << elapsedTime << " seconds" << endl << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    if (a[i] > a[i + 1])
    {
        cout << "Bubble sort : Incorrect results\n\n";
        break;
    }

cout << "Insertion sort: sorting an array of size " << n << endl;
begin = clock();
insertionSort(b, n);
end = clock();

elapsedTime = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
cout << "Elapsed time = " << elapsedTime << " seconds" << endl << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    if (b[i] > b[i + 1])
    {
        cout << "Insertion sort : Incorrect results\n\n";
        break;
    }

cout << "Write your statements to sort array c[] using qsort()\n";
cout << "qsort: sorting an array of size " << n << endl;

begin = clock();

// #### write your statements to sort array c[] using qsort().
//      Define your own compare function.
qsort(c, n, sizeof(double), compare_1);

end = clock();

elapsedTime = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
cout << "Elapsed time = " << elapsedTime << " seconds" << endl << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    if (c[i] > c[i + 1])
    {
        cout << "qsort : Incorrect results\n\n";
        break;
    }
delete[] a;
delete[] b;
delete[] c;
}
int main()
{
part_1(50000);

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: check if none of your array indexes get out of bounds. There is no automatic check in C, accessing an array with an out of bounds index is undefined behaviour.

Comment: There is an easy trick to fixing these types of errors: Replace your `double *a` with `std::vector<double> a;` followed by `a.resize(n);` and use `.at(i)` instead of `[i]`. That way you don't need to handle memory *and* you get a bounds check on every access of the data.

Comment: One problem is that the formatting makes the program hard to read and understand. Understanding it is required for further analysis though, so fix that problem first.

Comment: If you're trashing your stack, then you're probably writing past the end of your array. Using a std::vector will help you with that.
Aside: Any reason you didn't ask your professor for help?  It seems strange to pay for tuition and then not ask questions.

Comment: @UKMonkey he's not trashing the stack but the heap.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs due to memory corruption. Here memory corruption occurred because you wrote past the array limit.
Eg: If there is an array of 5 integers like

```
int array[5];
```

You should not do things like

```
int n=4;
array[n+1] = 10; //array out of bound memory write operation
```

C/C++ doesn't check for array out of bound operation. It permits such operation without compilation error. Result is, anything can happen to when you run program. So its the responsibility of the programmer to check such errors.

One such instance is found in your code.

```
void bubbleSort(double *x, int n)
{
// Implement the sorting function using the bubble sort algorithm.
double temp;
for (int j = 0;j < n;j++) {
    for (int i = 0;i < n;i++) {
        if (x[i] > x[i + 1]) {
            temp = x[i];
            x[i + 1] = x[i]; // out of bound write when i=n-1.
            x[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `bubbleSort` your array index goes out of range. Modify the function like shown below and you'll see what happens:

```
void bubbleSort(double *x, int n)
{
  // Implement the sorting function using the bubble sort algorithm.
  double temp;
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      if (i + 1 >= n)
      { // index is out of range
        cout << "Bummer\n";
        exit(1);
      }
      if (x[i] > x[i + 1]) {
        temp = x[i];
        x[i + 1] = x[i];
        x[i + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There afre most likely similar problems in your other sort functions.

Comment: That doesn't explain crash at `delete[]` statements, does it?

Comment: @freakish Yes it does. Accessing an array with out of bounds index is undefined behaviour. From then on anything can happen.

Comment: UB is a lazy explanation which (at least for me) is not an explanation at all. I think that the real reason might be (depending on allocator and os) because he creates 3 arrays in a row. In that situation the runtime may put them sequentially in memory and when he goes outside the first array he effectively corrupts meta data 
 for the second array. This causes crash when deleting second array.

Comment: Memory corruption errors aren't always detectable when they occur, but if the allocator adds sentinel data before and after each allocation they can be detected when you free the memory since it checks to make sure those bytes are unchanged. If they are you get the error then. Undefined behavior is the answer, but if and how those errors might be detected is implementation defined. As an example, the error might not be detected at all in release mode because only the debug allocator performs these checks.

Comment: @freakish Retired Ninja's comment applies here. That is exactly what happens on the OP's particular platform (Microsoft Visual Studio).